# How to make the background lines in PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"} more visible?

Tags: plotting, style, plot-themes

The following code

```
ListLogLogPlot[{1}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}]
```

[image: Out]

adds thin dashed gray lines to the background. Their visibility is OK in the notebook but they can barely be seen in an eps file. How to make the lines thicker or change their properties altogether (color, style etc)?

I have *Mathematica* version 10.0.2.

Comment: Have you seen `GridLinesStyle`?

Comment: No until now. Works like a charm, I can accept the answer if you care. Just for future reference, how can I get a list of all possible options for a given command such as ListLogLogPlot  ?

Comment: You can get the default settings using `ListLogLogPlot[{1}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}] // AbsoluteOptions`.

Comment: `Options[ListLogPlot]` gives you a list of possible options. (But not necessarily all.)

Comment: @Karsten7. Well, GridLinesStyle is there, thks.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96598/how-to-make-the-background-lines-in-plottheme-detailed-more-visible#comment261535_96598) by [J. M.♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m), one can use [`GridLinesStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GridLinesStyle.html) to change the appearance of grid lines:

```
ListLogLogPlot[{1}, PlotTheme -> {"Detailed"}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Gray, Dashed]]
```

[image: Out]